# SPI bit banging; MCP3208; Raspberry;error

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi

1. I am using Raspberry Pi 2 board with raspbian loaded. need to do SPI by bit banging & interface `MCP3208`.
2. I have taken [code from Github](https://github.com/raspberrypi-aa/raspberrypi-aa/blob/master/spi_bitbang_test.py). It is written for MCp3008(10 bit adc).
3. Only change I made in code is that instead of calling:

   `adcValue = recvBits(12, clkPin, misoPin)`

I called `adcValue = recvBits(14, clkPin, misoPin)` since have to receive **14** bits of data.

4. **Problem**: It keeps on sending random data ranging from 0-10700. Even though data should be max 4095. It means I am not reading data correctly.
5. I think the problem is that MCP3208 has max freq = 2Mhz, but in code there is no delay between two consecutive data read or write. I think I need to add some delay of 0.5us whenever I need to transition clock since I am operating at 1Mhz.
6. For a small delay I am currently reading [Accurate Delays on the Raspberry Pi](https://projects.drogon.net/accurate-delays-on-the-raspberry-pi/)

**Excerpt:**

> ...when we need accurate short delays in the order of microseconds, it’s
>   not always the best way, so to combat this, after studying the BCM2835
>   ARM Peripherals manual and chatting to others, I’ve come up with a
>   hybrid solution for wiringPi. What I do now is for delays of under
>   100μS I use the hardware timer (which appears to be otherwise unused),
>   and poll it in a busy-loop, but for delays of 100μS or more, then I
>   resort to the standard nanosleep(2) call.

Comment: Hi palu, I have checked using CRO.Exact problem is that bit banding in python is very slow. I have to mix C along with it to do that. As here http://codeandlife.com/2012/07/03/benchmarking-raspberry-pi-gpio-speed/

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Trying to figure it out now. When I get it dialed in I'll come back here and share the code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found some py code to simplify reading from the 3208 thanks to RaresPlescan.
https://github.com/RaresPlescan/daisypi/blob/master/sense/mcp3208/adc_3.py

I had a data logger build on the pi, that was using a 3008. The COTS data logger I was trying to replicate had better resolution, so I started looking for a 12 bit and found the 3208. I literally swapped the 3008 out for the 3208 and with this guys code I have achieved better resolution than the COTS data logger.